# Bring shapes to front on click in Kinetic JS

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas, kineticjs, shapes

Is there a way to bring shapes to the front of an html canvas once the shape has been 'selected' or clicked on in Kinetic JS? I can add styles to the shapes just fine but I am having trouble bringing the selected shape to the front. I've seen hundreds of examples using separate buttons to move them to the front. Is there a this.moveToTop()?

This is the code I am currently using for adding a shadow to my shapes once selected

```
triangle.on('mouseover touchstart', function() {
    this.setShadowOpacity(1);
    layer.draw();
});

triangle.on('mouseout touchend', function() {
    this.setShadowOpacity(0);
    layer.draw();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use triangle.moveToTop() inside a mouseover or click listener on the node.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/gQeEB/

[image][image]

```
circle1.on("click",function(){
    circle1.moveToTop();
    layer.draw();
});
```

Comment: So my situation is that I have two buttons to the left of my canvas that when clicked produces a black or red triangle. Each time you click the button, I call a triangle() function which creates a new triangle with a unique ID and adds it to the layer. Do you think it isn't working since I'm making my shapes using a function?

Comment: Adding shapes with a function works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/LVKzK/  You'll need to post more code to see where the problem is...

Comment: Ok I figured out what my problem was. Thank you so much for helping me out! I had a group in my function that I was adding to my shape before I added it to the layer. I ended up just putting all of my group attributes in my triangle shape and it worked!